# View not showing in Android

Tags: android, xamarin.android, android-view

I have 1px high Views with background to visually separate some linear layouts, but a random one of them which is no different to the others is not displaying and I cannot work out why.

```
  <ScrollView
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="0dp"
      android:layout_weight="2"
      android:background="#fff">
    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
      <LinearLayout
          android:orientation="horizontal"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:padding="15dp"
          android:id="@+id/startLoggingButton"
          android:background="@color/background_good">
        <TextView
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:text="START LOGGING"
            android:textSize="18dp" />
      </LinearLayout>
      <View
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="1px"
          android:background="@color/menu_text_color" />
      <LinearLayout
          android:orientation="horizontal"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:padding="15dp"
          android:id="@+id/voiceCommandsButton">
        <TextView
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:text="VOICE COMMANDS"
            android:textSize="18dp" />
      </LinearLayout>
      <View
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="1px"
          android:background="@color/menu_text_color" />
      <LinearLayout
          android:orientation="horizontal"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:padding="15dp"
          android:id="@+id/feedbackButton">
        <TextView
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:text="GIVE FEEDBACK"
            android:textSize="18dp" />
      </LinearLayout>
      <View
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="1px"
          android:background="@color/menu_text_color" />
      <LinearLayout
          android:orientation="vertical"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:padding="15dp">
        <TextView
            android:text="Data Sources:"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:textSize="17dp"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
        <CheckBox
            android:text="1 (default)"
            android:id="@+id/dataSourceStateHighways"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
        <CheckBox
            android:text="2"
            android:id="@+id/dataSourceCouncils"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
      </LinearLayout>
      <View
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="1px"
          android:background="@color/menu_text_color" />
    </LinearLayout>
  </ScrollView>
```

As can be seen in the example image, there is no line where it's highlighted in yellow:

[image: Example]

The weirdest thing is that the line shows up when viewed in dump view in the Android Device Monitor DDMS:

[image: DDMS]

*(StackOverflow is not letting me post my question because it doesn't have enough text so I'm just writing this a few times)(StackOverflow is not letting me post my question because it doesn't have enough text so I'm just writing this a few times)*

Comment: are you checking this in the layout editor?

Comment: try it without Linear layout below Give feedback and 1px View. Do you see the line or no. If yes, then just add 1 or 2 px marginTop to the below linear layout

Comment: most probably, it is overlapping. but give it a try

Comment: @SuhaibRoomy It works in layout editor and but not in app

Comment: @Deepakkaku Removing the lower linear layout still does not show the line below give feedback

Comment: can you include View inside the lnear layout of Give feedback?

Comment: give it a try in a different phone to test

Comment: Try to use `1dp` instead of `1px` not sure will this help but give it a try. Could be that something is messed up by `weights` and also your first `LinearLayout` should have height `wrap_content` instead of `match_parent`

Comment: It works on my physical phone but not the emulator. I didn't want to have to use 1dp because the lines render fatter than 1px, but using 1dp works I guess I'll just have to use that

Comment: You need to use emulator in 100% scale mode. If you are emulating a full hd screen, but your emulator is 1/4 of your full hd monitor  1px line may not be visible in some cases. You can test it by adding more "dumb" layouts in your ScrollView so it starts to scroll. During scrolling you'll see those lines flickering. You should not see this issue on a real device (or on the screenshots from emulator)

Comment: @DennisK this was exactly what was wrong. Would you like to add this as an answer so that i can accept it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the emulator in 100% scale mode. If you are emulating a full hd screen, but your emulator is 1/4 of your full hd monitor 1px line may not be visible in some cases. You can test it by adding more "dumb" layouts in your ScrollView so it starts to scroll. During scrolling you'll see those lines flickering. You should not see this issue on a real device (or on the screenshots from emulator)